# How do I move wxPython controls to another frame

Tags: wxpython

My main wxPython application wx.Frame is presently full of buttons and text fields as well as the main application display area.  All of the event handlers and UI code is contained in the MainFrame class which passes commands to a Control class.

I would like to move some of these controls from the MainFrame to a new SecondaryFrame that can be hidden.  I create an instance of SecondaryFrame and then use a menu item to Show and Hide it.

I seem to have a couple of choices for implementation:

1. Move all of the control create and handler code into the SecondaryFrame class.
2. Create a blank SecondaryFrame and populate it from within MainFrame leaving all of the handlers in place and making the controls members of MainFrame rather than SecondaryFrame
3. A combination of the two

Is seems like all of these options with require a significant refactoring of my code.  Am I missing a more obvious way to move already functional controls to a new frame?

Answer (score 1):

Each frame will need to have its own widgets. If you want both frames to have the same controls for some reason, then I would create a base class frame and have the other two inherit from it.

The handler code itself could be kept in a controller module. Then you would import the controller and do something like this:

```
mySecondaryFramesBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, controller.btnHandler)
```

That way you can bind the button in the first frame and the second frame to the same handler, so to speak.

You might also look into the idea of model-view-controller. You can read more about it at the following links:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/

Comment: The project is mostly MVC.  I do have a controller class, but I have tried to keep it GUI agnostic.  All event handlers and GUI related control code is in the MainFrame class.

Comment: The problem with having the handlers in a different class from the controls is that some of the handlers need to access the control itself, such as in the case of text controls and check boxes.  I don't see a clean way to have the handler in one class get data from a control in another.  It can work, but its feels sloppy.

Comment: I didn't know you wanted to pass data between the frames. Personally, I use pubsub for that. It makes passing data between classes extremely easy.